# For what reason I can access the resources by curl, but not in the browser?

Tags: cors

On the server side I'm using Rails. Purposely, I did not configure the CORS. Thus, as I expected, in the browser I can not do requests to the Rails server because I get this error:

[image]

But I can do for the terminal, using curl:

```
macabeus@macabeus-acer ~ $ curl http://localhost:3000/people
[{"id":3,"name":"macabeus","age":20,"created_at":"2016-07-31T22:45:05.490Z","updated_at":"2016-07-31T22:45:05.490Z"},{"id":4,"name":"foo","age":10,"created_at":"2016-07-31T22:45:24.415Z","updated_at":"2016-07-31T22:45:24.415Z"}]
```

For what reason the curl can, but the browser can't? I know how to solve this problem. I just want to understand what I asked earlier.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference should be whether the header `Origin: http://...` is sent in the request or not. `curl` by default doesn't send any extra headers, which you can confirm by running `curl` with `-i` option:

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:3000/people
```

If you send any arbitrary value in the `Origin` header along with the request like:

```
$ curl -i -H 'Origin: http://localhost:63343' http://localhost:3000/people
```

you should then see the same CORS error as in the browser.

The reason behind this is that the header `Origin` triggers if the request is a CORS one, i.e. comes from a different site, and depending on the configuration on the server side no `Origin` header may mean it comes from the same origin.